# Error "Cannot find module" when importing a remote JSON file in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, import

I have no problem with local JSON files. The following code works:

```
import data from "./example.json";
```

However, when comes to remote files like the one below it keeps erroring out saying "Cannot not find module"

```
import data from "https://www.example.com/example.json";
```

https://www.example.com/example.json is a valid URL. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) the json file from across the network. Therefore, you want to make an HTTP request for that specific file.

Try the following:

```js
let resourceAddress = 'https://www.example.com/example.json';
let data = '';

fetch(resourceAddress)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Do something with your newly loaded json data :)
    doSomethingWith(data);
  });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It works perfectly. I added your code to the onload function to load the JSON at start.